# Issue with .htaccess file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got the below two lines in a .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !(phpmyadmin)  .system/core/index.php
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 43200
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 43200
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
```

On the hosting there is a CMS that handles the rewriting of the URL that I cannot control and it was not made by myself.
I would like to have an exception for a folder. The folder www.mysite.com/event should not be handled in this way and just stay into the event folder where I need to display other page. 
How can I do that? Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create exception for any folder using `RewriteCond` as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(event|phpmyadmin)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ .system/core/index.php [L]
```

Comment: This is even better that what the CMS company had, but I didn't want to touch that file because is from a third party, but tested and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the `/event/` folder, create an htaccess file and add this:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

with no rules.

Comment: Yeah, that works! It was simple enough but not for me, .htaccess is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: @user1341765 Turning the rewrite engine on in the `/event` folder without any rules means that it supercedes rewrite rules in any of its parent directories. And since there are no rules, it's essentially turning the rewrite engine off in that directory (though it's sort of counter-intuitive since you are turning it **on**).